# Python Pandas copy string from one cell to another based on multiple conditions (length and content)

Tags: python, pandas

How to copy values in a cell from one column to another if they meet a specific condition. In this case, the length of the content of the cell (Greater than 1 ) and the contents of the cell (Does not include the letter 'a').

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data= np.array([[ 'a','b','c','xx','yy'], [ 'zz','ff','aa','a','b']])
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data.T, columns = ['col1', 'col2'])

   col1 col2
0   a   zz
1   b   ff
2   c   aa
3   xx  a
4   yy  b
```

The output would look like:

```
   col1 col2
0   a   zz
1   b   b
2   c   c
3   xx  a
4   yy  b
```

Here is where I stopped:

```
for x in dataset['col1']:
     if len(x) == 1 :
         ##replace col2 value with that of x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html)

```
mask1 = dataset.col2.str.len() > 1
mask2 = dataset.col1.ne('a')

dataset.assign(col2=dataset.col1.where(mask1 & mask2, dataset.col2))

  col1 col2
0    a   zz
1    b    b
2    c    c
3   xx    a
4   yy    b
```

Comment: in this case it checks if col1 length is less than col2 length. How can I specifically say if the contents in col1 is of length 1 then copy regardless

Comment: thanks looks great ! Is it possible to add another condition to the line, such as length == 1 and the content does not equal to 'a' ?

Comment: @piRSquared please check

Comment: So sorry, I was reall angry, now it is OK. Please give me know if something wrong with me, this problem is possible happens in future for me too.. (Maybe also in past, but I  did not remember.)

Comment: All is good from me.  I'd tell you otherwise.  I'll always try to act fair and correct my mistakes.  Sorry for any confusion from me.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can use the second parameter of `.loc`, which allows you to set a specific column name that will "receive" the value set by the right side of the `=` operator:

```
dataset.loc[dataset['col2'].str.len() > 1, 'col2'] = dataset['col1']
```

Comment: I would never advise using `apply(len)` over `str.len()`